# Wordpress CF7 Getting all values of the Drop-down from shortcode attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I manage to get the default value for the drop-down in cf7 but I wonder is it possible to get all the values from the shortcode.

It would be helpful to have them with pipes since I need to pass an ID and label to it.

If I’m not clear. I am trying to build the drop-down on this form:

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|55"
                    "Sales|45"
                    "Support|99"]
```

but those three values I need to pass via shortcode.

Reference: https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve that by creating a dynamic select field within `functions.php`. The select field values I am populating using a public variable.

```
function dynamic_field_values($tag, $unused)
{
    $dates = get_query_var('DATES');

    if ($tag['name'] != 'dates')
        return $tag;


    if (!count($dates ) > 0) {
        $tag['raw_values'][] = 'No dates available';
        $tag['values'][] = 'No dates available';
        $tag['labels'][] = 'No dates available';

        return $tag;
    } else {
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $tag['raw_values'][] = $date->id;
            $tag['values'][] = $date->id;
            $tag['labels'][] = $date->caption;
        }

        return $tag;
    }
}
add_filter('wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_field_values', 10, 2);
```